# Not able to present UIViewController with its Storyboard in a Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, swift-package-manager

I'm building a separate feature as a swift package. There is a view controller and its storyboard in the package. I'm having a problem instantiating and presenting the view controller. I get this error:

> Could not find a storyboard named 'MyIdCardVC' in bundle NSBundle ...

Both MyIdCardVC.swift and MyIdCardVC.storyboard are added to the package.

Here is part of the Package.swift declaration:

```
let package = Package(
name: "IDCard",
platforms: [
    .iOS(.v11)
],
products: [ 
    .library(name: "IDCard", targets: ["IDCard"]),
],
```

I'm presenting the package's view controller from my app like this:

```
import UIKit
import IDCard
 
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let vc = IDCard.MyIdCardVC.getStoryboardVC()
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 
}
```

the "getStoryboardVC" is a static extension method declared in the package

```
public extension UIViewController{

public static func getStoryboardVC() -> UIViewController {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
    return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
}
```

and here how the MyIDCardVC.storyboard looks:

[image]

Comment: In your `getStoryboardVC` function, try specifying a bundle. You can use NSBundle's `init(for:)` with `self.class` to get the bundle for your specific VC. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1417717-init) (Apologies for any syntax weirdness. I'm an ObjC guy).

Comment: appreciate your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work I did: let bundle = Bundle(for: self) . Then let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing: self), bundle: bundle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `Bundle.module` when instantiating the storyboard's view controller. `Bundle.module` refers to the containing package:

```
public extension UIViewController{
    
        public static func getStoryboardVC() -> UIViewController {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing: self),
 bundle: Bundle.module)// key part is Bundle.module
            return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        }
 }
```

Then in the app, I present the package view controller like this:

```
   @IBAction func openCard(){
        let vc = IDCard.MyIdCardVC.getStoryboardVC() as! IDCard.MyIdCardVC
        vc.personNo = "11111"
        vc.personId = "8888888"
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and in the storyboard, specify the module and uncheck Inherit Module From Target
[image]